# How to test a coturn server?

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn, coturn

I have tried setting up a coturn server with docker implementation with a Redis database. Now My concern is how to test this system. I tried testing it with the following

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/

But when I give the IP it shows the following error

`URI scheme xx.xx.xxx.xxx is not valid`

I would like to know what is the right way to do this.

Thanks in advance for your time – if I’ve missed out anything, over- or under-emphasised a specific point let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the scheme when specifying your `STUN or TURN URI`.

If the IP address of your TURN server is `192.168.0.1` you will put `turn:192.168.0.1` in that input field.

See [RFC 7065](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7065#appendix-A) for more examples!